# How much may a 30x increase in SpaceX revenue increase SpaceX stock value?

Tags: stocks, investing, investment-strategies

I know there is no exact answer to this, but I wonder if one of you readers with experience or education in these sorts financial things could depict what a reasonable outcome could be for SpaceX share holders.

Let's say, for example, an investor in SpaceX has $1,000,000 in share value.

What may be a reasonable estimate as to what the value range of those shares could be after SpaceX revenue increases by 30x like this video

https://youtu.be/giQ8xEWjnBs

thinks could happen?

Comment: SpaceX isn't publicly traded... while there is a valuation, it's far more unclear what could happen to that valuation than would be the case for a normal stock (which would already be in "who knows" territory, given stocks like Tesla or similar that are aspirationally priced already)...  Given it's not publicly traded, are you looking at what the change in the valuation would be?  Or what the change in actual cash would be (ie, dividends/profit sharing/etc. to the private owners)?

Comment: How much did the expenses rise?

Comment: @Joe - Why not post that as an answer instead of a comment. It is a good answer!

Comment: @JohnFx I meant it more as a clarification, hence the comment, but of course it is also for the most part an answer I suppose to the vague question.  However, a more specific question might be more answerable.

Answer (score 4):

Such a question cannot be answered.

First, value of shares depend more on profits. And growth in profits is different than revenues because of margins.

Second, value of shares depend on perception of results in the future, not present ones. It means that value of the shares will change together with expectations.

So for example, let's assume the revenues of the company will rise 30x and profits will rise 40x. And at present, investors have in their minds that they should rise 100x. In such configuration, the shares value will fall. What is more, they will fall not after the rise of revenues and profits is realized. They will fall at the time when investors get to know about this, when they change minds and start to believe that the growth will be 40x, not 100x they assumed earlier.

As you can see you cannot know almost anything about stocks value by looking only onto the future of revenues. You need much more information.